# SQL Find column with multiple possible values

Tags: sql, split

I have two tables:

TABLE 1

```
ID |    NAME   | VALUE
1  |TEST1      | '101;103;102;100'
2  |TEST2      | '101;102'
```

TABLE 2

```
|VALUE |
| 100  |
| 102  |
```

I need the rows from Table 1 where i can have ALL values from table 2. The values from table 2 are dynamic, so i need to create a procedure to search for these possible values.

My output should be in that example:

```
1  |TEST1      | '101;103;102;100'
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: t-sql, plsql? please explain what Database are you using.

Comment: Tables with multi-valued columns are almost always an indication of a bad database design decision. Normalizing such tables to first normal form almost always results in a much more usable design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing a join by trying to find the table 2 values in table 1. Then you can make sure all the values are getting joined. In SQL Server, something like this could work:

```
;with table1 as
(select 1 as ID,'test1' as name,'101;103;102;100' as Value union
select 2 as ID,'test2' as name,'101;102' as Value),
table2 as
(select '100' as value union select '102' as value)

select distinct a.ID,a.name,a.Value,count(*) as cnt
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on CHARINDEX(b.value,a.value,1)>0
Group by a.ID,a.name,a.Value
having count(*)=(select count(*) from table2)
```

That being said, the way the data is structured is really bad design and you should look into fixing the data model. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this in standard SQL as:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.value
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on ';' || t1.value || ';' like '%;' || t2.value || ';%'
group by t1.id, t1.name, t1.value
having count(distinct t2.value) = (select count(*) from table2 t2);
```

Note:  Not all databases support the standard `||` operator for string concatenation.  And a particular database might have more efficient methods.

AND -- very importantly -- you should fix your data model.  Strings should not contain lists of values like this.